# Emit to Parent triggers method but not value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When a user logs in we return the user_name and $emit it from the login.vue component to the App.vue component and to trigger an updateUser() method but the value is null even though I can alert or log the user_name

Tried to define the user_name a couple different ways user_name and this.user_name

login.vue -- login method

```
await this.$apollo.mutate({mutation: LOGIN, variables:{username: 
this.username, password: this.password}})
.then((result) => {
const user_name = result.data.login.user.User_Name
alert(user_name)
this.$emit('displayUser', user_name)
```

App.vue

```
   <v-list-item-title class="title" v-if="user_name" v-bind:user_name="user_name" > 
    {{user_name}}
    <v-list-item-subtitle>
```

Where the login.vue is contained in the app.vue component

```
  <v-content>
    <router-view v-on:displayUser="updateUser(user_name)"></router-view>
    </v-content>
```

Method - the alert is triggered with undefined

```
 updateUser(userN){
  alert(userN)
  if (userN === 'hide'){
    this.user_name = ''
   }
   else{
   this.user_name = userN;
   }
}
```

I can get the alert to pop up in the updateUser method but the value is null or undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely you need to replace your `<router-view>` code with this:

```
  <v-content>
    <router-view v-on:displayUser="updateUser"></router-view>
  </v-content>
```

Note that I am no longer passing `user_name` in the event handler. That is because `user_name` is not available in your template.

You are saying `On 'displayUser', call the 'updateUser' with the 'user_name' variable.` But `user_name` is not known to your `App` component.

But what you mean to actually say is `On 'displayUser', call the 'updateUser' method with whatever event parameters are sent back.`

---

You may also specify the event parameters by passing `$event` like so:

```
<v-content>
  <router-view v-on:displayUser="updateUser($event)"></router-view>
</v-content>
```

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers

Comment: Is user_name part of $event?

Comment: Per a quick [test](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-deeew), yes. Though the official documentation says it should be the actual DOM event. For your purpose, you will probably want to put in just the method name, without any parentheses or parameters.